# How to create cron job to close period each month

Tags: cron

I have a project where I have to update a field in my database every 1st day of each month and update it again every 10th after. 
This cron allow me to open a session and to close it. I would like to know how can I set up the 10th of the month.

1st day of each month I have : 0 0 1 * *
10th after it : ??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Cron expression that passes two dates in the day variable. Something like this would work:

```
0 0 0 1,10 * ? *
```

Expression description:

```
At 00:00:00am, on the 1st and 10th day, every month
```

You can use the comma in order to pass multiple variables in the day parameter in order to set multiple days to run.

A great resource for playing around with Cron statements is the [Cron formatter website](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html), which will let you enter statements, then give you the plain English logic that the statement will follow. It also shows which sections of the statement resolve to minutes, hours, days, ect.. It is really helpful for creating new statements in my opinion.

Comment: This is working well ! thank you so much for your help :)